# React: a value I just declared is prompted as "not defined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So the App I am coding is from Brad Traversy YouTube video "React JS Crash course 2021"
this is the error

```
  Line 19:23:  'text' is not defined         no-undef  
  Line 20:24:  'setText' is not defined      no-undef  
  Line 26:23:  'day' is not defined          no-undef  
  Line 27:24:  'setDay' is not defined       no-undef  
  Line 33:23:  'reminder' is not defined     no-undef  
  Line 34:24:  'setReminder' is not defined  no-undef
```

Here is where the error is coming from

```
import { useState } from 'react'
export const AddTask = () => {

const AddTask = () =>{

const [Text, setText] =useState('')
const [Day, setDay] =useState('')
const [Reminder, setReminder] =useState('false')


}


    return (
        <form className="add-form">
            <div className="form-control">
               <label>Task</label>
               <input type="text" placeholder="Add Task" 
               value={text} onChange ={
                (e) => setText(e.target.value)  
               }/>
            </div>
            <div className="form-control">
               <label>Day and time</label>
               <input type="text" placeholder="Add day and time"
               value={day} onChange ={
                (e) => setDay(e.target.value)  
               }/>
            </div>
            <div className="form-control form-control-check">
               <label>Set Reminder</label>
               <input type="checkbox" 
               value={reminder} onChange ={
                (e) => setReminder(e.currentTarget.checked)  
               }/>
            </div>

            <input type ="submit" value ="save task" className="btn btn-block"/>
                             
        </form>
    )
}


export default AddTask
```

I have tried capitalizing the first letter, checking the other variables, and making sure my code and the tutorial code were exactly the same up until that point. But to no avail.

here are the other components and main file
App.js

```
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Tasks from "./components/Tasks";
import AddTask from "./components/AddTask";
import { useState } from 'react'

function App() {

  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState ([{id:1, 
    text: 'Doctors Appointment',    
    day:'Feb 5 3:30 pm',
    reminder: true,
    },
    {id:2, 
        text: 'Meeting at School',    
        day:'Feb 9 2:30 pm',
        reminder: true,
        },
    {id:3, 
    text: 'Groceries',    
    day:'Feb 10 11:30 am',
    reminder: false,
            }]
               )
// 
const AddTask =(task) =>{
console.log(task)

}
// delete 
const deleteTask = (id) =>{
 setTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.id !==id))
}
// Toggle Reminder
const toggleReminder = (id)=>{

setTasks(tasks.map((task)=>task.id===id ? {...task, reminder:!task.reminder}:task))
console.log(tasks)

}

  return (
    <div className="container">

   <Header />

  <AddTask />

   {tasks.length > 0 ? <Tasks tasks={tasks} onDelete ={deleteTask} onToggle ={toggleReminder}/>:'no tasks to show'}



    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and

```
import React from 'react'
import { FaTimes } from 'react-icons/fa'

export const Task = ({task, onDelete, onToggle}) => {
    return (
        <div className={`task ${task.reminder ? `reminder`:''}`} onDoubleClick ={()=>onToggle(task.id)}>
            <h3>{task.text}  <FaTimes style ={{color:'red'
        , cursor:'pointer'}} onClick={()=>onDelete(task.id)}/></h3>
            <p>{task.day}</p>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Task
```

```
import Task from './Task';

 const Tasks = ({tasks, onDelete, onToggle}) => {


    return (
        <>
{tasks.map((task)=>(<Task key={task.id} task={task} onDelete={onDelete} onToggle={onToggle}/>))}
            
        </>
    )
}


export default Tasks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared mentioned variables inside `AddTask()` function. And you tried to access them outside of that function. Variables defined in function are not visible outside of that function.